# Store Procedure hit SQL Statement Ignored

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, indexing, concatenation, sql-insert

```
create or replace PROCEDURE GEN_STATEMENT_SP(indexNM IN VARCHAR2, tableNM IN VARCHAR2) AS
BEGIN 
DECLARE
uniqueSTMT  VARCHAR2(30);
nonUniqueSTMT VARCHAR2(30);
charOn VARCHAR2(5);
tempfld VARCHAR2(500) ;

CURSOR chkTyp IS(SELECT ES_UNIQUENESS from sys.dba_ind_columns where INDEX_NAME = indexNM and TABLE_NAME = tableNM);
CURSOR tblColumn IS(SELECT INDEX_NAME,listagg(COLUMN_NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY COLUMN_POSITION) COLUMN_NAME FROM sys.dba_ind_columns where INDEX_NAME = indexNM and TABLE_NAME = tableNM GROUP BY INDEX_NAME);

BEGIN

uniqueSTMT := 'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX';
nonUniqueSTMT := 'CREATE INDEX';
charOn := 'on';

if chkTyp.ES_UNIQUENESS = 'UNIQUE' then

   tempfield := uniqueSTMT || indexNM || charOn || tableNM || '(' || tblColumn.COLUMN_NAME || ')' ;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(tempfld);
end if;
END;
END;
/
```

Error list:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
9/17     PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
9/48     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
10/20    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
10/126   PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
18/1     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
18/11    PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'CHKTYP' reference is out of scope
```

Hi all, when i try to create a sample store procedure above. I hit SQL Statement  ignored. 
Need some help on this, Thanks alot.

Comment: Run `show errors` then **[edit]** your question and add the complete error you see.

Comment: Hi friend, added show_error in above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to DBA_ views (owned by SYS). Do you really need those? Switch to `USER_IND_COLUMNS` instead. Once you make that code work, expand it further (if necessary).

As of CHKTYP being improperly used: you declared a cursor, but never did anything with it (opened, fetched, ..., closed). On the other hand, why do you use cursors? Those are `SELECT` statements that return a single value (unless I'm wrong), so they might have been ordinary `SELECTs` (but yes, you might have to handle possible `NO-DATA-FOUND` exception).

Furthermore, there's no column ES_UNIQUENESS in `USER_IND_COLUMNS` view; what is is supposed to do? It exists in `USER_INDEXES`, but is called `UNIQUENESS`, without the ES_ prefix.

Shortly, you need to rewrite that code. Take it step by step, test frequently. Once you're sure that the first step was successful, go to the next.

Comment: my friend, DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(tempfield);

Comment: where i have to see the return value ?

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT needs to have the SERVEROUTPUT enabled. In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, you'd execute `set serveroutput on`.